# Synonyms from instance

Tags: oracle, synonyms

I have two different DB instances.
Is there any way to find out from instance2 (from all_synonyms view) list of all objects using synonyms from instance2 to instance 1 ...?

I want to, for example, connect on one instance, and query all object from another instance which have created synonyms for utilization in another instance ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_SYNONYMS WHERE DB_LINK = 'your_link_name_here';
```

?